# Single page app with API backend data preload

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api

Suppose we develop a single page application with heavy client side which talks with the server via API methods. If we are visiting index page which lists all records from db, it means that we are doubling every first request - one request to load all client side stuff and the other is an API request to the server to get `json` data and only after that everything runs normal. So my question is what is the best practice for this? Should we preload data on initial request in order to not making another one immediately or ..?

Comment: Returning json arrays with data in your initial response is a good way to minimize the number of requests for data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not doubling every first request,

the first request delivers the source code containing the scripts that will lazy load the data (ajax), so these would be 2 different request. That would result in faster loading time of the first page. For my opinion this is the cooler and more SPA way of dooing this, eg. showing a spinner while lazy load the data than wait longer for first delivery

by reading your question again you should rather not list all records from db at all but do some paging or infinite scrolling to minify server load

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't thinking from this perspective. PS: I perfectly understand that I should limit the number of records per request — it was just an example :)